# How to extract / unpack / unzip hudson.war in specified directory Linux / Windows and not on default?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, hudson, hudson-plugins

I downloaded hudson generic .war `hudson.war` from http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/download.php
and placed in some path.

On passing command

`java -jar hudson.war`

It extracts / unpacks / unzips `hudson.war` in `.hudson` directory under my home directory.

I want to extract / unpack / unzip under a directory / folder which I can specify.

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand, such situation arises when you  have limited space under your home directory.

Here are the steps and explanation for Windows and Linux

**Windows:**

By default
`java -jar hudson.war` will extract .war on path `%USERPROFILE%\.hudson`
For example in my case, in command terminal:

```
C:\Hudson>echo %USERPROFILE%\.hudson
C:\Users\osao.ORADEV\.hudson
```

This is the path where `hudson.war` is extracted.
For extracting in userdefined directory, you need to set `HUDSON_HOME` environment variable

To set persistent environment variables: Right click `My Computer` ==> `Properties` ==> `Advanced system settings` ==> `Environment Variables` ==> System variables `New`. 
Make sure that `HUDSON_HOME` is not already there. If yes, delete it.
Add `HUDSON_HOME`: `<your specified directory>`

Now open/restart command terminal. Check `echo %HUDSON_HOME%` it must be updated `HUDSON_HOME`

Now invoke 
`java -jar hudson.war` from the path where `hudson.war` is there.
You will notice that extraction is in specified directory.

**Linux:**

By default extraction happens in `$HOME`
You need to set `$HUDSON_HOME`
Based on your SHELL: `csh` or `bash`

**csh:**

```
mkdir /home/osao/myHudsonHome
setenv HUDSON_HOME /home/osao/myHudsonHome
echo $HUDSON_HOME
java -jar hudson.war
```

**bash:**

```
mkdir /home/osao/myHudsonHome
export HUDSON_HOME=/home/osao/myHudsonHome
echo $HUDSON_HOME
java -jar hudson.war
```

I hope this will help.